# get an element by finitely generated set

Tags: group-theory, matrices

I want to know the method to get a element in a finitely generated group by its generated set, is there a general way to calculate? For example, $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})=<a,b|a=\begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\-1 &0\end{pmatrix}, b=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}>$, how to write $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ as the multiplication of {$a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$}? Thanks.

Comment: The proof that ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $a$ and $b$ is constructive, so it tells you how to calculate an expression for any given element.

Answer (score 1):

The question in your first paragraph does not quite make sense: how is the element to be given in general, if not by a product of generators? In specific instances that question could make sense, such as the instance of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ where elements are given by matrices.

For the special case of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, one way to calculate is to use the presentation $\langle a,b \, | \, a^4 = b^6 = 1, a^2 = b^3 \rangle$, which expresses $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ as the free product of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ and $\mathbb{Z}/6$ amalgamated over $\mathbb{Z}/2$. Using this presentation it follows that $a^2=b^3$, which is minus the identity matrix, generates the center of the group. It also follows that every element of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ can be represented uniquely as the product of an element of the center times a word $w$ which alternates between the letter $a$ and one of the letters $b,b^{2}$.

So then, suppose you are given a matrix $M \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, and you wish to compute the corresponding word $w$. There is an inductive procedure that you can use to figure out the last "letter" of $w$, which will be one of the three elements $a,b,b^2$. Once you know that last letter, you can postmultiply $M$ by the inverse of that letter, which will shorten the representing word.

So, try some calculations, and you should be able to figure out the algorithm which from the matrix $M$ produces that last letter.

Comment: I don't understand the word problem reference here. The word problem says that you cannot, in general, determine if two words are equal. This does not mean that you cannot, when given an element, write it using the generators. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but my point is that the word problem is, in its usual statement, calculating *the wrong thing*. I do not understand how you are applying it to this problem.

Comment: I deleted my comment, I can see your point. Let me edit my first paragraph.

Comment: I disagree that it doesn't make sense - it is merely convenient (perhaps an artificial convenience) that an element is given in terms of the group generators and will not happen in a substantial number of cases. For example, in topology elements of mapping class groups will not usually be given in terms of the generators.

Comment: @user1729: The trouble is that the question in the first paragraph does not make sense *in general*. Maybe there's an interesting question here: given a group $G$, modelled by certain expressions for group elements and a certain formula for the group operation, and given a generating set, is there an algorithm which takes a representation of a group element and produces a word in the generators for that element? It can certainly be formulated for $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, for mapping class groups, … but is highly dependent on the model, it seems.

Comment: I am not sure I agree that it doesn't make sense - it is *trivial* if your group is given by generators and relations, but more complicated in general. I wonder if the solution for the trivial case can be ported over using Turing machines, but really I have no idea!